# Type Error when operating multi-frame tiff in PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tiff

I'm running a program which should take a multi-frame tiff file (black and white animation), scan through all of the frames and determine their mean pixel values, effectively allowing me to plot Z-axis profile. Program works for single frame tiffs however I keep running into the Type Error every time I try to run in with the animation.

```
im = Image.open('example_recording5.tif')
width,height = im.size
image_lookup = 0
n = 1
while True:
     try:
        im.seek(n)
        n = n+1
    except EOFError:
        print "End of sequence",  n
        break; 
#this sets a length argument (n) and allows to determine no of frames

class ImageSeq:
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.im = im
    def __getitem__(self, ix):
        try:
            if ix:
                self.im.seek(ix)
            return self.im
        except EOFError:
            raise IndexError 
result = []
c= 0 #(number of process repeptitions)

for index, frame in enumerate(ImageSeq(im)):
     total=0
     totalnew=0

    for i in range(0,width):
        for j in range(0,height):
            total = float (im.getpixel((i,j))[0])
            totalnew = totalnew + total
            mean_pixel_value = totalnew / (width * height)
    c = c+1    
    print c, mean_pixel_value
```

The error which shows up is as follows and as far as I understand, it is caused by indexing with the frames in ImageSeq; what could I do to prevent it?
''
    total = float (im.getpixel((i,j))[0])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'''

Comment: Looks like the result of `im.getpixel((I,j))` returns an integer which can't be indexed with `[0]`

Comment: Upon checking into the results, it seems that this is caused by some intriguing way of getpixel not being able to handle anything else than greyscale material made greyscale exclusively via im.convert('LA') (doesn't want to interact with tiffs created by ImageJ or ImageMagick). Do you have any idea about how I could convert every frame to greyscale separately (as .convert will remove the Z axis information, leaving behind a single frame tiff)?